# installing virtualbox apt-get wants to download gcc-4.8 --> replacing gcc-4.9?

Tags: software-installation, apt, virtualbox, gcc, repository

I'm trying to install virtuabox on Debian 8.3 using the `contrib` repos.
When I use `apt-get install virtualbox` it wants to install `gcc-4.8`, but I already have `gcc version 4.9.2` installed.
What am I doing wrong? Is it safe to do so I can keep my gcc-4.9.2?

**apt-get output**

```
apt-get install virtualbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cpp-4.8 dkms gcc-4.8 libasan0 libgcc-4.8-dev libgsoap5 libvncserver0
  linux-compiler-gcc-4.8-x86 linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64
  linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common linux-headers-amd64 linux-kbuild-3.16
  virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
Suggested packages:
  gcc-4.8-locales gcc-4.8-multilib gcc-4.8-doc libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg
  libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libquadmath0-dbg
  vde2 virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
Recommended packages:
  linux-image
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cpp-4.8 dkms gcc-4.8 libasan0 libgcc-4.8-dev libgsoap5
  libvncserver0 linux-compiler-gcc-4.8-x86 linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64
  linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common linux-headers-amd64 linux-kbuild-3.16
  virtualbox virtualbox-dkms
  virtualbox-qt
0 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/35.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 148 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]n
```

**apt-cache policy virtualbox**

```
virtualbox:
  Installed:           (none)
  Installation candidates: 4.3.32-dfsg-1+deb8u2
  Version table:
     4.3.32-dfsg-1+deb8u2 0
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib amd64 Packages
```

Comment: English output would help.

Comment: updated question.

Comment: How did you install your gcc 4.9.2?

Comment: I don't think it will replace 4.9, though I'm not sure why it is trying to install 4.8 either. On my system, virtualbox certainly doesn't pull that in as a dependency. More details would help. What does `apt-cache policy virtualbox` say? Also, give the complete output for the `apt` command, and also the `apt` command itself.

Comment: edited the Question

Comment: @Cdrmoi Note that you need to actually notify the person you are addressing of your comment, by using @. Otherwise he/she will not be notified.

Comment: @FaheemMitha ok, I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified, using my handy jessie chroot (to avoid experimenting on my main system, also jessie), that installing the default jessie `virtualbox` package (`4.3.36-dfsg-1+deb8u1`) does actually pull in gcc 4.8 packages, as follows.

```
apt-get install virtualbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cpp-4.8 dkms gcc-4.8 kmod libasan0 libgcc-4.8-dev libgsoap5 libvncserver0 linux-compiler-gcc-4.8-x86 linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64
  linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common linux-headers-amd64 linux-kbuild-3.16 virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
Suggested packages:
  gcc-4.8-locales gcc-4.8-multilib gcc-4.8-doc libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libquadmath0-dbg vde2
  virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
Recommended packages:
  linux-image
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cpp-4.8 dkms gcc-4.8 kmod libasan0 libgcc-4.8-dev libgsoap5 libvncserver0 linux-compiler-gcc-4.8-x86 linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64
  linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common linux-headers-amd64 linux-kbuild-3.16 virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
0 upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 35.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 149 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

This is harmless. *However*, the default jessie virtualbox package is version 4.3, which is rather old. You should use the jessie backport 5.0 `virtualbox` package. If you add

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and run `apt-get update`, you can install the jessie backports virtualbox 5.0 package with the command

```
apt-get install -t jessie-backports virtualbox
```

The installation of the jessie backports 5.0 virtualbox package will *not* install gcc 4.8.

For reference, note with jessie backports added, the available virtualbox packages are:

```
apt-cache policy virtualbox
virtualbox:
  Installed: 5.0.14-dfsg-1~bpo8+1
  Candidate: 5.0.14-dfsg-1~bpo8+1
  Version table:
     5.0.16-dfsg-2 0
         50 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ unstable/contrib amd64 Packages
 *** 5.0.14-dfsg-1~bpo8+1 0
        100 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/contrib amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.3.36-dfsg-1+deb8u1 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     4.3.32-dfsg-1+deb8u2 0
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 1):

After installing virtualbox you will keep the new version `gcc version 4.9`

Before installing virtualbox you can verify existing versions, you will find the `gcc-4.8` and `gcc-4.9`

```
gcc-4.8/unknown,stable,stable,stable,now 4.8.4-1 amd64
```

and

```
gcc-4.9/stable,stable,stable,now 4.9.2-10 amd64
```

**Update**

You need to `cat` the `/proc/version` file. This file identifies the kernel version that is currently running and gcc version used.

```
cat /proc/version
```

Get the exact path for gcc and g++ 4.9

```
which gcc-4.9
which g++-4.9
```

use `export` to point `gcc` to the `gcc-4.9` path and `g++` to the `g++-4.9` path.

Something like:

`export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.9
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.9`

Comment: `dpkg -l gcc*` gave me 4.1 up to 4.9. That solved my questions :). How do I specify what version should be used when I run gcc?

Comment: @Cdrmoi You don't specify. The release/version specifies the default you use. And this answer doesn't actually explain anything, as far as I can see. It's almost complete gibberish. Sorry.

Comment: You shouldn't mess around with the compiler variables like that; the Virtualbox packages end up installing `gcc-4.8` because that's what the kernel was built with, so the Virtualbox kernel module needs to be built with `gcc-4.8`, not `gcc-4.9`. Just follow the package setup and use the defaults, and everything will be fine – the module will be built with the right compiler, and the default compiler for everything else will still be 4.9.